# Altair: apply selection and ~selection within LayerChart

Tags: python, visualization, altair

The use case here is to analyze the results of clustering; We'd like to choose a cluster and a feature (so two dropdowns), and display a layered histogram that shows the distribution of "feature" for points in "cluster", layered with the distribution of "feature" for points outside "cluster." **The additional constraint is we need standalone HTML, so we can't use anything requiring a python kernel.**

After also exploring `plotly` and `bokeh`, `Altair` gave me the closest solution (below).

Input data is like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import altair as alt

df = pd.DataFrame({"cluster": np.random.choice([1, 2], size=100)})  # cluster labels
df["feature1"] = np.random.normal(loc=1, scale=0.7, size=100) + df["cluster"]  # a feature column
df["feature2"] = np.random.normal(loc=10, scale=1, size=100) - 3*df["cluster"]  # a second feature column
```

```
   cluster  feature1  feature2
0        2       3.4       4.5
1        2       2.4       3.9
2        1       1.6       5.7
3        1       1.6       5.7
4        2       3.3       4.5
```

Which I have first melted to:

```
dfm = pd.melt(df.set_index('cluster', drop=True), ignore_index=False, var_name='feature')
dfm.reset_index(inplace=True)  # Get cluster labels as a column again
```

```
   cluster   feature  value
0        2  feature1    3.4
1        2  feature1    2.4
2        1  feature1    1.6
3        1  feature1    1.6
4        2  feature1    3.3
```

I have code working except that I have to use `VConcatChart` rather than `LayerChart` because with the cluster selection I need to apply `selection` to one histogram (points in the cluster) and `~selection` to the other (points outside the cluster).

```
input_dropdown = alt.binding_select(options=[1,2], name='cluster  ')
selection = alt.selection_single(fields=['cluster'], bind=input_dropdown, name='filter_cluster', init={'cluster': 1})
input_dropdown2 = alt.binding_select(options=['feature1', 'feature2'], name='feature  ')
selection2 = alt.selection_single(fields=['feature'], bind=input_dropdown2, name='filter_feature', init={'feature': 'feature1'})

x_domain = alt.selection_interval(bind='scales', encodings=['x'])

hist1 = alt.Chart(dfm).transform_filter(
    selection & selection2
).transform_joinaggregate(  # to achieve normed histogram
    total='count(*)'
).transform_calculate(  # to achieve normed histogram
    pct='1 / datum.total'
).mark_bar(
    opacity=0.3, interpolate='step', color='green'
).encode(
    alt.X('value:Q', bin=alt.BinParams(maxbins=50), title="feature value", axis=None),
    alt.Y('sum(pct):Q', title="frequency"),
)

hist2 = alt.Chart(dfm).transform_filter(
    ~selection & selection2
).transform_joinaggregate(  # to achieve normed histogram
    total='count(*)'
).transform_calculate(  # to achieve normed histogram
    pct='1 / datum.total'
).mark_bar(
    opacity=0.3, interpolate='step', color='black'
).encode(
    alt.X('value:Q', bin=alt.BinParams(maxbins=50), title="feature value"),
    alt.Y('sum(pct):Q', title="frequency")
)

conc = alt.vconcat(
    hist1,
    hist2
).add_selection(
    selection
).add_selection(
    selection2
).configure_concat(
    spacing=0
).add_selection(
    x_domain
).resolve_scale(
    x='shared'
)

conc
```

[Here is an image of the resulting viz, not the interactive form.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99ZWw.png)

Is there any way to achieve this but where the two histograms are layered?

Comment: Does replacing `alt.vconcat` with `alt.layer` not do the right thing? I tried that and everything appears to be working correctly.

Comment: @jakevdp wow I feel sheepish. I think after failing with `alt.layer` I did some refactoring where I put the `add_selection` on the combined chart rather than on each one, and that must have eliminated the error I was seeing. Many thanks for taking the time to look, and for the package you built.

Comment: Makes sense! Glad it's working now

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, the solution was to replace `alt.vconcat` with `alt.layer`.